# Configuring pig relation with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm having troubles understanding the relation between Hadoop and Pig.
I understand Pig's purpose is to hide the MapReduce pattern behind a scripting language, Pig Latin.

What I don't understand is how Hadoop and Pig are linked. So far, the only installation procedures seem to assume that pig is run on the same machine as the main hadoop node.
Indeed, it uses the hadoop configuration files.

Is this because pig only translates the scripts into mapreduce code and send them to hadoop ?

If that's the case, how could I configure Pig in order to make it send the scripts to a distant server ?

If not, does it mean we always need to have hadoop running within pig ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pig can run in two modes:

1. **Local mode.** In this mode Hadoop cluster is not used at all. All processes run in single JVM and files are read from the local filesystem. To run Pig in local mode, use the command:

   ```
   pig -x local
   ```
2. **MapReduce Mode.** In this mode Pig converts scripts to MapReduce jobs and run them on Hadoop cluster. It is the default mode.

   Cluster can be local or remote. Pig uses the HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME environment variable to find Hadoop installation on local machine (see [Installing Pig](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_pig_install.html)).

   If you want to connect to remote cluster, you should specify cluster parameters in the pig.properties file. Example for MRv1:

   ```
   fs.default.name=hdfs://namenode_address:8020/
   mapred.job.tracker=jobtracker_address:8021
   ```

   You can also specify remote cluster address at the command line:

   ```
   pig -fs namenode_address:8020 -jt jobtracker_address:8021
   ```

Hence, you can install Pig to any machine and connect to remote cluster. Pig includes Hadoop client, therefore you don't have to install Hadoop to use Pig.

Comment: One last question : when you're using the MapReduce mode, does `ls` shows you the cluster's files (like if you were using ssh) ?

Comment: Yes. In my version of Pig (0.11.0-cdh4.6.0), `ls` shows the full path, including the protocol (`hdfs://` for cluster files and `file://` for local files).