# Pig job always fails

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, kerberos

I am using hadoop-2.6.0 secured with kerberos and pig version 0.13.0. I have a file in hdfs as below

**count**

```
1,ck
2,second
```

**Pig Script**

```
a = load '/user/username/newtable';
b = distinct a;
dump b;
```

**Exception**

```
2015-02-03 11:34:45,237 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2015-02-03 11:34:45,431 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: AttemptID:attempt_1422943403169_0001_r_000000_3 Info:Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in fetcher#3
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.ShuffleSchedulerImpl.checkReducerHealth(ShuffleSchedulerImpl.java:357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.ShuffleSchedulerImpl.copyFailed(ShuffleSchedulerImpl.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyFromHost(Fetcher.java:351)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.run(Fetcher.java:193)


2015-02-03 11:34:45,432 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2015-02-03 11:34:45,434 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:
```

When running a map reduce job in pig facing such exception. But map reduce job works fine using sqoop import.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you check your pig script fails while executing distinct a; or in loading the newtable? try to do a dump a; before loading relation b.

Comment: dump a working fine. Because in pig 0.13.0, just loading and dump is not execute map reduce job.

Answer (score 2):

This error:
**at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.**

typically indicates an issue with Pig being able to communicate with your Namenode.  This most often happens if you are running Pig from another machine like your workstation or a gateway machine.
Possible causes:

- You have two network interfaces setup and you are routing through the wrong one.
- Your /etc/hosts file does not have the correct IP address for your Namenode.
- Your DNS Server is not resolving your Namenode correctly (probably not the issue if Sqoop is working unless it is local and Pig is remote)
- Your Pig configuration file is pointing to either the wrong IP or Hostname for the Namenode. See this post:[Configuring pig relation with Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832085/configuring-pig-relation-with-hadoop)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have checked all these things. The problem occurs only if i enable LDAP for active directory in windows. If i have not enable LDAP then pig job working fine.